# Why does changing what a reference points to not throw an error?

Tags: c++, reference, rules

Iv got to the stage in my c++ study concerning references. It states the following rule:

Once a reference is initialized to an object, it cannot be changed to refer to another object.

Iv wrote a short code (as asked to in an exercise) that is meant to prove this rule correct.

```
int y = 7;
int z = 8;

int&r = y;
r = z;
```

Can someone explain why this code compiles without any errors or warnings?

Comment: A good way to demonstrate the error condition you want is to create a struct that contains a reference to an int. Create two instances of that struct (call them a and b) that are initialized with two different ints. now try to "a = b". That will generate an error, because the only way it could succeed is by changing what a reference refers to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`r = z` does not change what `r` "points to."  It assigns the value of `z` to the object pointed to by `r`.

The following code does the same thing as  your code, but using pointers instead of references:

```
int y = 7;
int z = 8;

int* p = &y; // p points to y
*p = z;      // assign value of z to the object pointed to by p (which is y)
```

Comment: For the sake of this example I must try to reseat the reference just to show that the compiler will not allow this. How would I write this?

Comment: To rephrase your question:  "How can I do [this thing that is not possible to do]?"

Comment: @James - it's not often that I laugh audibly while reading SO.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It does not make the reference alias to something else but it changes the value of what `r` contains.

```
int&r = y;
```

`r`is reference to `y`

```
r = z;
```

changes value of `y` & `r` to value of `z` by assigning value of `z` to `r` & hence `y`.

Answer (score 4):

```
int&r = y;
r = z;
```

It does NOT change the reference. Rather it changes the *value* pointed to by the reference variable. The reference variable is just yet another name of `y`. So `r=z` is equivalent to

```
y = z;
```

That is, `r=z` changes the *value* of `y`.

Reference variable *cannot* be reset to refer to *another* variable, in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You're not changing the reference; you're setting a new value to the referred object. After this example you should note that y==8.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `r = z` you are not reseating the reference, instead you are *copying* the value of `z` into `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when study <<thinking in c++> charpter11.
here is my understanding code: the second compile error seems can not be simulated. but can understand. you can draw a picture to see what x, y, z, and ref2 point to.

```
/**
Write a program in which you try to
    (1) Create a reference that is not initialized when it is created.
    (2) Change a reference to refer to another object after it is initialized.
    (3) Create a NULL reference.
**/
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // 1 
    //int& ref1;      // compile error: 

    int x = 10;
    int& ref2 = x;
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "ref2 = " << ref2 << endl << endl;

    // 2 
    int y = 20;
    ref2 = y;   // 这里没有编译错误，ref2的指向并未改变，其指向的空间由10改变为20
    cout << "ref2 = " << ref2 << endl;
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl << endl;

    int z = 30;
    ref2 = z;
    cout << "ref2 = " << ref2 << endl;
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    cout << "z = " << z << endl;

    // 3 
    //int& ref3 = NULL;   // compile error: 
    return 0;
}
```